# How do I evaluate this sum :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^3}{(n+1)2^n} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

I have tried evaluating this series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^3}{(n+1)2^n} $$

using some methods but it's seems to me that it is very hard. However, I noticed that the series converges faster than the Riemann series.

**My question here is:**

Is there some mathematical technique for evaluating the above series?

**Note1:** Here, $H_n$ denotes the harmonic numbers.

**Edit** : I have a wrong type I meant in the denomenator $2^n$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: it evaluates to 0.38360530295885199... --- which is not recognized as having a closed form representation by the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index)

Comment: sorry , I have a wrong typo I meant :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^3}{(n+1)2^n} $ not $3^n$ in the denominator and i edited the question

Comment: with the $2^n$ in the exponent it's 0.96630012055722... do you really need more accuracy?

Comment: What is "the Riemann series"?

Comment: i meant sum(1/n^k) , for k greater then 1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By multiplying out the factor $H_n^3$, it is not too hard to see that your sum can be written as a rational linear combinations of special values of weight $4$ multiple polylogarithms. The Maple package [HyperInt](https://bitbucket.org/PanzerErik/hyperint/wiki/Home) (by Erik Panzer) can perform simplifications with multiple polylogarithms. According to this software,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^3}{(n+1)2^n}=\frac{\log(2)^4}{12}-\frac{\pi^4}{144}+\frac{\log(2)^2\pi^2}{6}+\log(2)\zeta(3).
$$
The algorithm the software uses is described in Panzer's paper "[Algorithms for the symbolic integration of hyperlogarithms with applications to Feynman integrals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465514003658)" (there is also [a version of the paper on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3385)).

Answer (score 7):

Let $g(a)=\frac{a}{1-a}, f(a)=\log(1-a)$ and $h(a)=\log^2(1-a)$. Let $\square^m$ denote a $m$-dimensional unit hypercube.

The following is an application or reformulation of the above infinite series evaluation.
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{h(\frac12xz)-xh(\frac12z)+xzh(\frac12)-zh(\frac12x)}{x(1-x)z(1-z)}dxdz=
\frac{\log^42}{12}-\frac{\pi^4}{144}+\zeta(2)\log^22+\zeta(3)\log2.$$
**Proof outline:** Since $\frac1k=\int_0^1x^{k-1}dx$, we may write
\begin{align} \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{t^nH_n^3}{n+1}&=\sum_{n\geq1}t^n\int_0^1w^ndw\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n\int_{\square^3}x^{i-1}y^{j-1}z^{k-1}dxdydz \\
&=\int_{\square^4}dxdydzdw\sum_{n\geq1}(tw)^n\sum_{i,j,k=1}^nx^{i-1}y^{j-1}z^{k-1}\\
&=\int_{\square^4}\frac{dxdydzdw}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\sum_{n\geq1}(tw)^n(1-x^n)(1-y^n)(1-z^n)\\
&=\int_{\square^4}dxdydzdq\frac{g(tw)-g(twy)-g(twx)+g(twxy)-g(twz)+g(twyz)+g(twxz)-g(twxyz)}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}.
\end{align} 
Next, make a repeated use of the integral evaluations
$$\int_0^1\frac{g(tw)-g(twy)}{1-y}dy=-\frac{f(tw)}{1-tw}$$
and
$$\int_0^1\left(\frac{f(twx)}{1-twx}-\frac{f(tw)}{1-tw}\right)\frac{dw}{1-w}=
\frac{xh(t)-h(tx)}{2tx}$$
to arrival at the double integral upon replacing $t=\frac12$. The rest follows from the series evaluation algorithm that Julian Rosen alluded to.  $\square$

**Remark.** This approach actually could prove (directly) the easier-looking
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{H_n^2}{(n+1)2^n}=\frac13\log^32+\zeta(2)\log2-\frac12\zeta(3).$$